# Manage Payment Flow Through Php Api

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, stripe-payments, payment-processing

i had done simple payment and reccuring payment in paypal using php..but now i want do payment like ebay system..i want manage seller account,middle patry account,buyer account. when buyer order for any product that time money tranfer from buyer account to middle party account and when buyer got product at that time money tranfer from middle party to seller account..i want make this system using php..i tried for create customer and add charge in stripe..but i dont know how to deduct charge from middle party in stripe php api

Comment: Please post the corresponding code. Only then would we be able to help.

Comment: i want only some referce link for manage seller-middle party-buyer money tranfer through stripe

Comment: using charge object i had tranfer money from buyer to middle party.and it work good..but my problem is how can i deduct that from middle party and tranfer that to seller account using api call

Answer (score 0):

You can check the whole Stripe API available for PHP at this link and check what meets your needs:

https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#intro